# Is it a good practice to write a jpql query of another entity in a JpaRepository defined for different entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities in my database CustomerDetails & LineDetails. In CustomerDetails table there is a flag pdf_generate_flag, datatype of which is set to boolean.
So everytime, when there is a request to add or update either CustomerDetails or LineDetails i need to change the flag to false.
So for CustomerDetail object, i set the pdf_generate_value in the CustomerDetail object itself, so while updating it will set the value to false.
But for LineDetails i need to write a query to update its value to false explicitly.

I can write this method in CustomerRepository and autowired it in LineImpl and called it but it is never called from CustomerImpl.
So should i write this method in LineRepository? Which one is the good practice. Working in both the ways.

This is my lineRepo and i am updating customer entity from it.

```
@Repository
public interface LineRepository extends JpaRepository<LineDetails, Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("update CustomerDetails c set c.pdfGenerateFlag = 0 where c.id = :id")
    void changePdfGenerateFlag(Long id);
}
```

Same method should i write it in customerRepo and autowire it in LineImp or should i directly call LineRepo? Which one will be a good practice?

I have tried both the ways and it is working.

Comment: Seems like you have a relationship between the two entities. Just an opinion: Your service layer should handle setting the CustomerDetails.pdfGenerateFlag flag when it makes LineItem modifications and deal with the entity object directly - this will ensure that any instances of CustomerDetails you have cached reflect the current value and don't become out of synch with what is in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa) reference says

> Spring Data JPA aims to significantly improve the implementation of
> data access layers by reducing the effort to the amount that’s
> actually needed.

As for me, it means whatever you use to work with data, you should work with data you use. Using one entity's repo for modifying another entity is absolutely misleading. `JpaRepository` is just a suitable abstraction designed to simplify an interaction with database and can be replaced with JDBC call or whatever. What will you think of this method functionality in a while, looking at the name of the `LineRepository.changePdfGenerateFlag(long)` method? How will you understand it works with another entity?

Your necessity to reset the flag of one entity when another has been changed is a kind of business requirement, so it would be wise to make it a part of the business layer, not infrastructure.

If I did this task, I would create separate service methods for updating and creating entities and within each of them the opposite repository would be invoked

```
@Transactional // atomicity for both create CD and update LD
public CustomerDetails createCustomerDetails(CustomerDetailsDto dto) {
    CustomerDetails customerDetails = customerDetailsRepository.save(create(dto));
    // btw, do they both have the same ID? How do you handle it?
    lineDetailsRepository.changeFlag(<line_detail_id>, <flag_value>);
    return customerDetails;
}
```